# How to automatically add \! in subscripts?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
$a_1$

$a_{\!1}$
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image: Spacing]

I like the spacing on the lower one much more.

**Is there a way to automatically use `\!` on all subscripts so that I don't have to type it everytime? If this is not the optimal way to achieve this spacing, I'm eager to learn a better way, of course.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can redefine the command `_`. Therefor you must change the catcode of the sign. The redefinition in the example should be done in the preamble. I did it in the document body to demonstrate the behaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
$a_1$

$a_{\!1}$

 \catcode`\_\active
 \def_#1{\sb{\!#1}}

$a_{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Instead of changing the underscore global, you can set the mathcode of the token to redefine (suggest by David Carlisle and improved by egreg):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
$a_1$

$a_{\!1}$

\catcode`\_=12
\mathcode`\_="8000
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1}{\sb{\!#1}}

$a_{1}$
\begin{equation}
1+1=1\label{eq_1}
\end{equation}
Text \ref{eq_1} Text$_1$
\end{document}
```

However the best is to avoid `_` in labels.

Comment: Thanks, but this produces errors when I use underscores in `\label{}`. How can I fix this?

Comment: @FooBar What exact errors you get? You might try to put the nasty code in the preamble so that the catcode is already `\active` at `\begin{document}` when the `.aux` file is read.

Comment: @tohecz It is in the preamble and I get `Missing \endcsname inserted` in the `.aux` file on lines like `\usedref{eq:label_with_underscore}`.

Comment: This does not work at all. Your new code does not change the spacing but also does not give any warning or error.