# Command for formatting only first level of nested subscripts?

Tags: subscripts

I'd like to create a command which only targets the first "level" of the indexes. I'll illustrate with some examples, using `\qq` as the command in the first line, and the "real" LaTeX code on the line below:

```
d\qq{SA}
d_{\mathrm{SA}}

d\qq{SA_j}
d_{\mathrm{SA_{\mathit{j}}}}

d\qq{S_{j,k} A_j}
d_{\mathrm{S_{\mathit{j,k}} A_{\mathit{j}}}}

d\qq{S_{j,k} A_{j,k}}
d_{\mathrm{S_{\mathit{j,k}} A_{\mathit{j,k}}}}
```

The compiled code should look like this:

[image: picture]

I have absolutely no idea on how to de this, or if it can be done just using `\newcommand`.

Please help, doing this manually drives me nuts :)

Comment: The second should be `$d_{\mathrm{SA}_{j}}$`: mark as `\mathrm` only the bit that should go in upright type.

Comment: The question is related to: [How to automatically add \! in subscripts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108706/how-to-automatically-add-in-subscripts/108709#108709)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\qq#1{_{\mathchoice
{\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}}%
{\hbox{$\textstyle#1$}}%
{\hbox{\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0$\scriptstyle#1$}}%
{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}%
}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$d\qq{SA}$
$d_{\mathrm{SA}}$


$d\qq{SA_j}$
$d_{\mathrm{SA_{\mathit{j}}}}$

$d\qq{S_{j,k} A_j}$
$d_{\mathrm{S_{\mathit{j,k}} A_{\mathit{j}}}}$

$d\qq{S_{j,k} A_{j,k}}$
$d_{\mathrm{S_{\mathit{j,k}} A_{\mathit{j,k}}}}$

\end{document}
```

The spacing is not exactly the same as you are subscripting a boxed S not the S directly so you lose some fine adjustments to subscript positioning.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for – thank you! And it's nice that you point out the details about the subscript spacing.

Comment: Just noticed it's not working in fractions in inline math mode: [snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/ed6X2kd.png), Code: `$\phi = \arctan \left( \frac{d\qq{SA_0}}{d\qq{A_0A_j}} \right)$`

Answer (score 2):

The following is adapted from David Carlisle's answer, and from [this answer to a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9334/911): make `_` a macro unto itself, and use the `\sb` macro (which retains the old behaviour of `_`) to define a new behaviour depending on the surrounding math style.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\catcode`_=\active
\def_#1{\mathchoice
  {\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}{\sb{\mathit{#1}}}{\sb{\mathit{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$d_{SA}  \;\;  d_{SA_j}  \;\;  d_{S_{j,k} A_j}  \;\;  d_{S_{j,k} A_{j,k}}$

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Romanised first-level subscripts]

You can switch this behaviour off and on as you like, using macros

```
\def\romansuboff{\catcode`_=8}
\def\romansubon{\catcode`_=active}
```

and then using `\romansuboff` to turn off the custom behaviour, and `\romansubon` to turn it back on.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you're starting from a wrong premise. If you say

```
$d_{\mathrm{SA}_{j}}$
```

you'll have none of these problems. Maybe you want to use a shorthand for `\mathrm`:

```
\newcommand{\qq}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
```

and type

```
$d_{\qq{SA}_{j}}$
```

Keep properly segregated different semantics.

Comment: This actually seems like a good option... can't believe I didn't thought about nesting the subscripts in that way.