# Subscript spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts

I have a question similiar to the post:
[How to change default for spacing around binary relations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55512/how-to-change-default-for-spacing-around-binary-relations).
In particular, I would like to make subscripts look less cramped. According to another post
([Increase the space between operator in subscript/superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113556/increase-the-space-between-operator-in-subscript-superscript)), there doesn't appear to be a good way to do this. Currently, I do the following (more or less what the author in the second referenced post suggests).

```
\documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\ts}[1]{\, #1 \,}

\begin{document}

\[
    \sum_{i \ts{=} 1}^{n} a_{i}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, the \ts command makes the LaTeX harder to read. Does anyone have any ideas about how to get the desired spacing while keeping the LaTeX simple? Ideally, I would just write the following:

```
\[
    \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}
\]
```

but get some extra space around the equals sign in the subscript of the summation.

Comment: By design TeX doesn't add space around binary operation or relation symbols in subscripts and superscripts. Which is desirable, in my opinion, contrary to yours.

Comment: Well, perhaps my eyes will get used to the cramped style. I would probably consider this a design flaw, though: I think it would be better to have a variable to adjust the space around binary operations and relation symbols in subscripts and superscripts, even if the default value of the space is zero.

Comment: Unfortunately this is how TeX was designed, so without a markup it's impossible (or at least quite difficult) to get the spacing you want.

Comment: Idea 1: Make the important symbols active and define them via `\mathchoice` to have additional space.

Idea 2: Where is `\scriptstyle` defined, which is probably the root of the missing spacing.

Comment: I think this is duplicated: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108706/how-to-automatically-add-in-subscripts/108709#108709

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It's not obvious (at least to me), how to use that answer to solve my problem. I want to add some space around *all* binary operations and relation symbols in subscripts *and* superscripts. Perhaps you could make an answer out of your technique...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is a good idea but you could do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\sb[1]{_\text{$#1$}}

\begin{document}

\[
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}
\]
\[
    \sum\sb{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}
\]

\end{document}
```

Here I've redefined the standard command `\sb` which by default does the same as `_`, you could go further and redefine `_` but history shows that if you do that usually you end up breaking something.